# Using jQuery to Remove Formatting

Tags: jquery, formatting, masking

I have a text box, a social security text box, that has a mask on it.

So when it is typed into the text box, it comes out as:
123-45-6789

But when I send it to the database, I want to strip the dashes (-). I have tried

```
SSN = ($('#SSNField').val()).replace("-", "");
```

But this only removes the first instance of dash, so it gets sent to the database as

12345-6789

I have also tried `replaceAll`, but I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
var s = $('#SSNField').val().replace(/\-/g, '')
```

You basically need a `/g` for your code to work.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know exactly what /g did.

Comment: it is basically a global flag